# How to receive all data sent by server?

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, char

We have `recv` [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx) which is receiving specific amount of bytes. I need to write a function which is returning a pointer to `char` which contains ***all*** data, responsed by server.

```
char* receive_all()
{
    //Don't know how...
}
```

The thing is I couldn't know what amount of bytes the server responded until I recieved that, therefore I couldn't create an array of an appropriate size like

```
char* buf = new char[1000]; //Maybe the server's response have more than 1000 bytes
```

Comment: are you using UDP or TCP ?

Comment: @mpromonet Does it matter?

Comment: Using TCP you need to call several times recv to be sure to get what was send with a unique send.

Answer (score 0):

```
int receive(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{
    size_t toread = len;
    char  *bufptr = (char*) buf;

    while (toread > 0)
    {
        ssize_t rsz = recv(sockfd, bufptr, toread, flags);
        if (rsz <= 0)
            return rsz;  /* Error or other end closed connection */

        toread -= rsz;  /* Read less next time */
        bufptr += rsz;  /* Next buffer position to read into */
    }

    return len;
}
```

Comment: Ok, what size of buf, passing to the function shoudl should be?

Comment: Your buffer size. The buffer is defined out of the function scope.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin I think you misunderstood what the OP wants.

Comment: @user3663882, you specify how big you want your buffer before you use this function: e.g. `#define BUFSZ 1024` .. `char buf[BUFSZ] = {0};` `int len = receive(sock, (void*)buf, BUFSZ, 0);` .. then `buf` is filled with the data received from the `recv` call and the number of bytes actually received is returned. You don't make a call to `recv` without the #bytes you want to receive (and subsequently, `recv` returns the number of bytes actually received).

Comment: @txtechhelp And user3663882 wants a function that allocates the buffer for him/her, of the appropriate size to hold everything it receives, and that receives everything until the end of stream.

Comment: Your version of receive does not take into account `EINTR`, that is not actually an error in this context.

Answer (score 0):

malloc and realloc functions can be used to dynamically allocate and reallocate the buffer. Just in case if the data can go really huge then use a simple linked list.

```
struct node {
  char buf[4096];
  struct node *next;
};
```

To make it more efficient tune your buffer size with page size of your server, generally it is 4096 bytes. So what you can do is create a new node everytime you receive data from

> ssize_t rsz = recv(sockfd, bufptr, toread, flags);

and finally to read the entire data traverse the linkedlist.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the current pending size by `ioctl(fd,FIONREAD,&bytes_available)`. Since you tagged the question as C++, just use `std::vector<char>`. It has a `.resize(bytes_available)` method.

Of course, packets are received asynchronously, so the value of `bytes_available` should be understood as a minimum.